# Perform JS function on all ID's on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fullpage.js

```
   var hslider_slider_id = jQuery('.hslider_misc_holder').attr('id').slice(8);
   activate_width_checker(1080, 1080, 'responsive', hslider_slider_id);
```

This code is overriding a conflict between fullpage.js and WP Hero Slider I have two pages with two sliders. This code is being called successfully on the first slider, but not the second. I need to refactor the code in order to make sure the JS function is called on the second slider, which has the same ID .hslider_misc_holder, not just the first. Do i need to run it through a loop in order to achieve this??

Or use .map

The conflict is causing the Hero Slider not to load full size.

Ant

Comment: Call it again when your second page is loaded.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear there are two slider on each page, the second slide on each page isn't being affected by the function. Just need to run the function through a loop to call it on all instantiations of the ID. Not a great Programmer that's why I'm asking!!!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code inside an IIFE to avoid naming conflicts (e.g. `(function(){}())`) ?

Answer (score 0):

First, the . prefix signifies a class and not an ID. The # prefix should be used for selecting an element by id.

Update your question to include an HTML snippet so I can understand the structure.

It sounds like you want to select multiple elements by class and then loop though these and pass the id (or a direct reference to the object) into the function.

```
    var sliders = jQuery('.hslider_misc_holder');
    $.each(sliders, function(idx, slider) {
            activate_width_checker(1080, 1080, 'responsive', $(slider).attr('id'));
    });
```

Comment: Sorry your right it is a class as the code indicates!!

Comment: I just want the second slider to be affected by the function at the moment it is not being called the first slider is. Just need to loop through all of the instances of this class on the page.

Comment: The class is part of the parent element of the slider

Comment: Yes I added the .each() function to loop the code and that then called all the instances of that class on the page. Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

--- UPDATED

When you call `.attr("id")` the jQuery will return only the ID of the first element in the set. You will have to perform a look trought the set:

```
$(".hslider_misc_holder").each(function () {
  activate_width_checker(1080, 1080, 'responsive', $(this).attr("id").slice(8));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a REGEX in selector. For example, on onclick event.
On two elements in html:

`<div id="div1">DIV1</div>
<div id="div2">DIV2</div>`

Now in JavaScript:

`

```
$('[id ^= DIV').on('click', function(){alert();});
```

`

REGEX selector allow find all id in html with same pattern.

I hope help you.